# react bind onclick to function in export

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to learn React. I am still confused about how to pass state between components and the App.

What I am trying to accomplish is an Onclick="" from another component calls a function in the main export App function:

In this essence it should be able to delete a polygon drawn into google map.

The component for the form:

```
class SuperCoolFarm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
        this.state = {value: ''};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Button variant="secondary" size="lg" onClick={() => {
                        //call function DeletePolygon from app
                    }}>
                        Remove Polygon
                    </Button>
        );
    }


}
```

The main app:

```
export default function App() {

    const DeletePolygon = React.useCallback(polygon => {
        polygonRef.current = polygon;
        //empty out the paths
    }, []);

  
    return (<Container>
        <Row>
            <Col>
                <SuperCoolFarm thePath = {path}/>
            </Col>
            <Col>
                <GoogleMap
                    onLoad={onMapLoad}
                    mapContainerStyle={mapStyles}
                    zoom={8}
                    center={center}>

                    {path && path.length > 0}
                    <Polygon
                        options={{
                            fillColor: `#2196F3`,
                            strokeColor: `#2196F3`,
                            fillOpacity: 0.5,
                            strokeWeight: 2
                        }}
                        // Make the Polygon editable / draggable
                        editable
                        draggable
                        path={path}
                        // Event used when manipulating and adding points
                        onMouseUp={onEdit}
                        // Event used when dragging the whole Polygon
                        onDragEnd={onEdit}
                        onLoad={onLoad}
                        onUnmount={onUnmount}
                    />
                    )}
                    {path &&
                    path.map((pos, key) => {
                        return <Marker key={key} label={"" + key} position={pos}/>;
                    })}
                </GoogleMap>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Container>)


}
```

Am i going about this the right way?

Fiddle: The idea is that delete polygon removes the polygon from the map by emptying out the Paths object.
https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-frog-d6203?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the function as a prop to your component

```
<SuperCoolFarm thePath={path} onDeletePoligon={DeletePoligon}/>
```

And use it in your component like this

```
< Button variant="secondary" size="lg" onClick={() => {
   props.onDeletePoligon()
 }}>
```

Comment: Just wondering is the code structured bad, or is passing around functions like this normal in react?

Comment: It is pretty normal